# jQuery submit() ignores event handler in nested condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, form-submit

The problem I am having is that I cannot get the event.preventDefault() to stop the form from submitting in the nested if statements below the first condition testing the Parent Ticket against Original Ticket (which does work as expected).  It appears to loose the ability to call the event handler.  I have tried return false, event.stopPropagation(), event.stopImmediatePropagation() and nothing works inside the nested conditions.  Could anyone shed some light on this for me?

```
$( "#editTicket" ).submit(function( event ) {
    var inputTicket = $('input[name=parentTicketID]').val();
    var orginalTicketID = $('input[name=id]').val();

    //  Parent Ticket cannot be the original ticket
    if ( inputTicket == orginalTicketID )
    {
        $("#parentTicketMessage").html("The parent ticket number is the same the original ticket.  Please change the parent ticket number.");
        $('input[name=parentTicketID]').focus();
        event.preventDefault();  
    }

    if ( inputTicket != orginalTicketID && inputTicket.length > 0)
    {   
        $.get("/resources/cfc/qmdata/ticket.cfc?method=getTicketArray&returnformat=json",{id:inputTicket}).done(function(data) 
        {
            var thisTicketID = JSON.parse(data);

            if ( thisTicketID.toString().length == 0 )
            {
                alert("inside bad ticket");
                $("#parentTicketMessage").html("This is not a valid ticket number.  Please change the parent ticket number.");
                $('input[name=parentTicketID]').focus();
                event.preventDefault();  
            }

            else if (thisTicketID[0].ticketID.toString().length > 0 && thisTicketID[0].parentTicketID.toString().length > 0)
            {
                $.get("/resources/cfc/qmdata/ticket.cfc?method=getTicketArray&returnformat=json",{parentTicketID:inputTicket}).done(function(data2) 
                {
                    var thisParentTicketID = JSON.parse(data2);
                    //  We need to check to see if the parentTicketID has not been used on this page.
                    if (thisParentTicketID.toString().length != 0 && thisParentTicketID[0].ticketID != inputTicket)
                    {
                        alert("already used");
                        //  This is the child ticket check and is already being used...stop processing and display message
                        $("#parentTicketMessage").html("This ticket number is already a child ticket and cannot be used.");                     $('input[name=parentTicketID]').focus();
                        event.preventDefault();  
                    }
                });
            };
        });
    }   
});
```

'''

What I am trying to accomplish is simply add a message to the form when certain conditions are met and stop the form from being posted until the user fixes the issue.

Comment: Hi Rob, put event.preventDefault() on the beginning of the callback... so everything will work like a charm

Comment: I have tried putting it everywhere with no luck.  Could you tell me where you think it should be in relation to one of the nested conditions?